# Is there a way to both include PCSE and Prais-Winsten correction in a fixed effects model in R (similar to the xtpcse function in Stata)?

Tags: r, regression, plm, economics, autocorrelation

I want to estimate a fixed effects model while using panel-corrected standard errors as well as Prais-Winsten (AR1) transformation in order to solve panel heteroscedasticity, contemporaneous spatial correlation and autocorrelation.

I have time-series cross-section data and want to perform regression analysis. I was able to estimate a fixed effects model, panel corrected standard errors and Prais-winsten estimates individually. And I was able to include panel corrected standard errors in a fixed effects model. But I want them all at once.

```
# Basic ols model
ols1 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data)
summary(ols1)

# Fixed effects model
library('plm')
plm1 <- plm(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data, model = 'within')
summary(plm1)

# Panel Corrected Standard Errors
library(pcse)
lm.pcse1 <- pcse(ols1, groupN = Country, groupT = Time)
summary(lm.pcse1)

# Prais-Winsten estimates
library(prais)
prais1 <- prais_winsten(y ~ x1 + x2, data = data)
summary(prais1)

# Combination of Fixed effects and Panel Corrected Standard Errors
ols.fe <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + factor(Country) - 1, data = data)
pcse.fe <- pcse(ols.fe, groupN = Country, groupT = Time)
summary(pcse.fe)
```

In the Stata command: xtpcse it is possible to include both panel corrected standard errors and Prais-Winsten corrected estimates, with something allong the following code:

```
xtpcse y x x x i.cc, c(ar1)
```

I would like to achieve this in R as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that my answer will completely address your concern, these days I've been trying to deal with the same problem that you mention.

In my case, I ran the Prais-Winsten function from the package *prais* where I included my model with the fixed effects. Afterwards, I correct for heteroskedasticity using the function vcovHC.prais which is analogous to vcovHC function from the package *sandwich*.

This basically will give you White's/sandwich heteroskedasticity-consistent covariance matrix which, if you later fit into the function coeftest from the package *lmtest*, it will give you the table output with the corrected standard errors. Taking your posted example, see below the code that I have used:

```
# Prais-Winsten estimates with Fixed Effects
library(prais)
prais.fe <- prais_winsten(y ~ x1 + x2  + factor(Country), data = data)

library(lmtest)
prais.fe.w <- coeftest(prais.fe, vcov = vcovHC.prais(prais.fe, "HC1")

h.m1 # run the object to see the output with the corrected standard errors.
```

Alas, I am aware that the sandwhich heteroskedasticity-consistent standard errors are not exactly the same as the Beck and Katz's PCSEs because PCSE deals with panel heteroskedasticity while sandwhich SEs addresses overall heteroskedasticity. I am not totally sure in how much these two differ in practice, but something is something.

I hope my answer was somehow helpful, this is actually my very first answer :D